# How to use value of variable's value in IF condition

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Here, there is a variable "question", and that has a value that is variable too that is "Q4_1", and I need to execute if the condition on the basis of that value of "Q4_1". So how should I call the variable's variable's value?

```
question="Q4_1"

<%if (value of (=question)="1"  then %>            
    <tr><td>Some text</td></tr>
<%end if %>
```

Comment: Is the `question` variable a javascript variable or vbscript? If it's javascript then I believe it would not be possible since the vbscript's server-side code will execute first before the page is displayed.

Comment: @JohnOdom **question** is the vbscript variable, and it contains the database column as value, so would it be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `Eval()` function to evaluate an expression:

```
Dim question
Dim Q4_1

question ="Q4_1"
Q4_1 = "1"   
If Eval(question) = "1"  Then
    Response.Write "Some text"
Else
    Response.Write "Other text"
End If
```

This example will send "Some text" to the client.